# IIS user credential

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, credentials

I'm developing an ASP.NET application that requires to run with windows user credential.
In my developing environment I use IIS Express 8.0, so the application run by default with user credential, while in production environment I use IIS 7.5, and application run as "IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool".
In IIS manager -> Application Pools I can change identity to "LocalService", "LocalSystem" or "NetworkService", but I can't find something like "Windows user credential".
Defaul Web Site Authentication is already set as "Windows authentication", but it is my understanding that this only avoid external user to connect.
Am I missing something?

Comment: found a solution: In IIS Manager, in SiteName -> Authentication, "ASP.NET Impersonation" and "Windows Authentication" was correctly enabled, but I was missing a setting in Web.config asp file.
`<identity impersonate="true" />` in `<system.web>` wasn't enough (as it was in IIS6), but I also needed to add `<system.webServer>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
 </system.webServer>`

Answer (score 0):

As i undestand you need to configure impersonation. Please follow [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730708%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) link for instruction.